# linq to entity stored procedure return that needs extra joins after the fact

Tags: c#, .net, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities

I have a stored procedure that returns the table type. However, the EF model that has the stored procedure, only returns the present table class, but no associated classes. So when I traverse my referenced (child/parent) tables, I get nulls everywhere for those referenced table values.

I know this is expected as the stored procedure returns only that table (select * from that table), but I now would like to create a join clause AFTER calling the store procedure to get access to the rest of the referenced tables in my EF model.

Here is my code , slightly modified to make it easy to understand what I need...

```
var coll = db.SearchContacts(keyword,param1,param2)
//returns Contact types,works great
```

...now what I would like to do....(although I know syntax is off)

```
var ExtColl = coll join db.Address on coll.Address 
               join db.Department on coll.Department <- something similar
```

...so that I may now have access to that department (department.desc), 
or address (address.civic) info from this contact.

I am at a loss as to how to implement this style of formatting AFTER I have already received it from the stored proc in the db.

---

Ok, so here is an update of what I am doing...

```
var ps = from d in db.SearchContacts(param1,param2)
         select d.Id;
var p = from e in db.Contacts
        .Include("Table1Ref")
        .Include("Table2Ref")
        .Include("Table3Ref")
        Where(BuildOrExpression<DBMOdel.Contact,long>(e=>e.Id,ps.ToList()))
        select e;
```

Now I am getting the return I want except for one thing....
there are tables that reference further referenced tables 
that I would like to add, and Include does not allow 
me to add them unto Contacts directly as these tables are not 
referencing Contact but another table that references Contact 
one layer/level further...so contacts references address 
and address references province...
and I need to get access to the province info (such as description) 
but need to finish my join statement properly....

So I am thinking of using join statement, but do not know the syntax for assigning or joining of this kind...
Contact -> Address on AdressId, Address -> Province on ProvinceId

SO i am thinking my linq statement would look like this...

```
var p = from e in db.Contacts
        .Include("Table1Ref")
        .Include("Table2Ref")
        .Include("Table3Ref")
        Where(BuildOrExpression<DBMOdel.Contact,long>(e=>e.Id,ps.ToList()))
->      join o in db.Province on o.ProvinceId equals e.Address.ProvinceId
        select e;
```

but am not getting the desired effect...can anyone help?
I think I might be also mixing linq to sql or object with linq to entity...
this is the error I am getting for it

"The key selector type for the call to the 'Join' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider."

Answer (score 2):

There is no SQL syntax to join tables to stored procedures, so EF won't be able to do this either.

Alternatives:

- Do the joins in memory (linq to objects).
- Do the joins in a stored procedure and map it to a [complex type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456824.aspx).

The latter option is likely to perform (much) better, but is less flexible. It's up to you to weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: Second one is the best option (complex type), regarding performance. EF doesn't fit all cases, so be open to any other option. For example, I use EF just to save/update/delete data for simple objects. To retrieve data (master/detail, calculated fields, reports), I just use datatables, because of performance and practical use.

Comment: could you show me the syntax for doing the first though, as this is what I am having diffculty with...as stated, my return sits in the variable ...var coll ....., and I need to do a join or include syntax with that and other tables..... so I add an extra variable .... var ExtraColl = "syntax to get what I need using the coll variable for the joins".....

Comment: It would be a `coll.ToList()` and then use [`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx). But it depends on what you do with your contacts. If you don't always need all address and department info, you may consider fetching the information on a per contact basis.

Comment: I added a comment to get proper code formatting instead of replying to your reply, if you dont mind taking a look at it, I would be very greatful

Comment: You can do `.Include("Address.Province")` or more in general `.Include("Children.Children")` or `.Include("Parent.Children")` etc. BTW it is better to edit your original post in stead of adding new information and questions in an answer. It is not an answer after all :).